# Pushing records to AWS DynamoDB with AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to push a record from the AWS Lambda function to the AWS DynamoDB. I can successfully push a record from my pc using AWS API but when I deploy the code to AWS I'm stuck.

Here's the example code that can successfully push a record from my PC:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
  region: "eu-west-1",
  endpoint: "https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const params = {
  TableName: "hello-world-bot",
  Item: {
    timestamp: Date.now(),
    chat_id: 123,
    text: 'text',
  },
};

console.log("Adding a new item...");
docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
});
```

And the result in DynamoDB:
[Screenshot from DynamoDB console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlV2n.png)

And here's the code I'm trying to deploy to Lambda:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
  region: "eu-west-1",
  endpoint: "https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
});
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.helloworld = (event) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: "hello-world-bot",
    Item: {
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      chat_id: 123,
      text: "text",
    },
  };

  console.log("Adding a new item...");
  docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(
        "Unable to add item. Error JSON:",
        JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)
      );
    } else {
      console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
    }
  });
  return { statusCode: 200 };
};
```

And the trouble is that there are no any records in DynamoDB when Lambda function runs.
Here are logs from CloudWatch when I pull Lambda external API and try to run the function:

```
START RequestId: d9e171c2-a763-4df1-9ec3-06d79eb68a1e Version: $LATEST
2021-08-13T06:03:01.974Z    d9e171c2-a763-4df1-9ec3-06d79eb68a1e    INFO    Adding a new item...
END RequestId: d9e171c2-a763-4df1-9ec3-06d79eb68a1e
REPORT RequestId: d9e171c2-a763-4df1-9ec3-06d79eb68a1e  Duration: 45.04 ms  Billed Duration: 46 ms  Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 88 MB  Init Duration: 524.54 ms
```

As you can see there are no any errors saying anything about permissions or else.
These are the user permissions whose credentials are used with this function in Lambda:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGetItem",
                "dynamodb:GetItem",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWriteItem",
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
                "dynamodb:UpdateItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:120400915578:table/hello-world-bot"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Try not explicitly setting the DynamoDB endpoint (`https://dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`). You should never need to do this except if you run a local DynamoDB mock. This might already be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've pointed out in the comments of the other answer, their return statements do not seem entirely correct. I would prefer to use async-await syntax for promises which are supported by lambda and the AWS SDK out of the box.

This would change your code to look like the following:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

module.exports.helloworld = async (event) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: "hello-world-bot",
    Item: {
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      chat_id: 123,
      text: "text",
    },
  };

  console.log("Adding a new item...");
  try {
    await docClient.put(params).promise();
    return { statusCode: 200 };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:",
        JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    return { statusCode: 500 };
  }
};
```

PS: As pointed out in the comments as well, you don't need to set the endpoint for DynamoDB if you're using the default endpoint. And since you're running the function as a Lambda an `AWS_REGION` environment variable will be set automatically, so you also don't need to configure this yourself (unless you want to access a DynamoDB table in another region).

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working but now I'm struggling with another trouble:
 `"message": "User: arn:aws:sts::120400915578:assumed-role/hello-world-0001-bot-dev-eu-west-1-lambdaRole/hello-world-0001-bot-dev-helloworld is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:eu-west-1:120400915578:table/hello-world-bot",`
I cannot get why it shows error despite the fact that permissions are defined.

Comment: I see in your question you are using user credentials in lambda? You should never do that, but you should use a Lambda execution role instead. See this for more info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html

Comment: Hey! It works, and your link to AWS docs perfectly fits. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

your `return { statusCode: 200 };` ends the lambda invocation, but it does not wait for the `put` request to finish. It probably don't even wait for it to start, actually.

Either return your main function from the `put` callback, or use promises. Example with promise:

```js
module.exports.helloworld = async (event) => { // <- use async
  const params = {
    TableName: "hello-world-bot",
    Item: {
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      chat_id: 123,
      text: "text",
    },
  }

  console.log("Adding a new item...")
  // Create a promise and return it
  return docClient
    .put(params)
    .promise()
    .then(() => {
      console.log("success")
      return {statusCode: 200}
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log("error: ", e)
      return {statusCode: 500}
    })
}
```

Also, as pointed out by @jens in the comments, explicitely setting a dynamodb endpoint is not required

Comment: Your return statements are not correct as far as I can tell, they will only return from the inner method and not from the handler method itself. You can simply use `docClient.put().promise()` and combine it with async-await for your error handling.

Comment: My bad, I will edit using promise. Agreed it's better anyway

Comment: I've added an answer as well :)

Comment: It's good to have examples for both approaches :)

Comment: But in your example, the return statements are still not correct, since you're only returning from the inner anonymous method and not from the `helloWorld` method. Where you've stated `don't return here` the function will still have an implicit return. Lambda might have executed the DynamoDB action, but will not return the values as you're expecting them to be returned.